# unable to run cin before cout statement

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, cin, cout

I have just started working in Visual Studio Code.

I am facing a problem that my code is not working in VS Code even though **it is working in an online compiler.** A basic "hello world" program is running fine in VS Code.

I am using the mingwin g++ compiler running the code using VS Code (<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + B</kbd>).

My code is given below. If I uncomment the `cout` statement, the complete code will work fine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t;
    //cout << "hello-world";
    cin >> t;
    cout << t;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: To add onto @Yksisarvinen's comment, please include expected behavior and actual behavior.

Comment: It is not taking the input.

Comment: @ShubhamGarg what leads you to believe that is the case? Please fully describe the steps you're taking, what you expect to happen on screen and what's actually happening.

Comment: when I run this c++ code I expect a blinking cursor waiting for an input from me(user) but it is as if someone has frozen the terminal screen.      Then I close the vs code window and open it again to terminate that terminal process

Comment: So what happens if you type into that "frozen" terminal screen and press enter? Depending on the terminal, you may not get a blinking cursor.

Comment: Please check the above image (I have edited the question)

Comment: If I type something it does not show anything to me on screen.

Comment: Even after typing something and pressing enter, it does not show me anything and ctrl + c is also not working so I use alt + f4 to terminate the process

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you only see a blinking cursor waiting for an input from user is because your program runs cin first before the cout. If you uncomment line 6 in your code, you will see "hello-world" displayed first before the blinking cursor. I see no error in your code even you uncomment that one.

Comment: yes I know there is no error in the code but still it is not running but if I uncomment that line it will

Comment: Does typing a number in the terminal and then pressing "Enter" display the number you just typed? That's what your program is doing

Comment: No, it does not display anything to me. The terminal is just frozen.